# Bug in JS remove div classes (only mobile devices scroll)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Thanks for your help in Advance.

I have created an html page where user click on image and it expends (show another Div) on click. It is working exactly what i was looking for, but there's only one problem. When the same page is opened in mobile devices e.g Iphone and you click on the first image it works fine, but if you scroll the page down the expended image disappear. I shell be very thankful if you check the code below and open the following page in your mobile device to understand what i mean. I think i missing something in Javascript.

Here's the page: http://netstormdev.com/test.html

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.openEntry').remove();
    $('.entry').hide();

    var startPosX = $('.preview:first').position().left;
    console.log(startPosX);
    $('.entry, .preview').removeClass("first last");
    $('.entry').each(function() {
      if ($(this).prev('.preview').position().left == startPosX) {
        $(this).prev('.preview').addClass("first");
        $(this).prevAll('.entry:first').addClass("last");
      }
    });
    $('.entry:last').addClass("last");
  });
  $(window).trigger('resize');

  $('.trigger').click(function() {
    $('.openEntry').slideUp(1000);
    var preview = $(this).closest('.preview');
    preview.next('.entry').clone().addClass('openEntry').insertAfter(preview.nextAll('.last:first')).slideDown(1000);
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
    $('.openEntry').slideUp(1000).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .preview {
    width: 32.4%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 23px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .preview {
    width: 32.4%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 23px;
  }
}
.entry.last.openEntry {
  display: none;
}
.cuox .preview {
  display: none;
}
.preview {
  width: 24.6%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 23px;
}
.entry {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.close_button {
  text-align: right;
}
.smalle {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview red">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/c.jpg">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="mix preview green">
  <p>
    <a class="trigger" href="#">
      <img class="smalle" src="http://netstormdev.com/img/a.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="close_button">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://netstormdev.com/img/b.jpg">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure what all that is supposed to look and work like. With all images looking the same, and the large images different from the smaller images, it's very confusing.

Comment: @Connum The images used are just for example (test use), the actual images will be different, what i need is just to stop the large images from disappearing when viewed on mobile device.